# Batch intersection in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, iteration

I've written the following arcpy script to loop through a directory and intersect all the shapefiles in it with a certain other shapefile:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
env.workspace = "F:/Tiled_Shapes/"

outws="F:/Clipped_Shapes/"

#checkout ArcGIS spatial analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
inshape = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","All")

clipfile = "F:/Clip_subset.shp"

for i in inshape:
  filename=os.path.splitext(i)[0]
  outPolygons= outws + str(filename) + '.shp'
  inFeatures = [i,clipfile]
  arcpy.Intersect_analysis(in_features=inFeatures,join_attributes = ALL, out_feature_class=outPolygons)
```

Whats unnerving, is that rather than getting an error, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here? When I use the intersect feature on the same data in ArcMap, it works fine. Now when I try to do it to a whole directory its failing.

Comment: after your `inshape = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","All")` line, add a `print inshape` to see what's in the list

Comment: Why aren't you using Clip if you're trying to Clip? Are your datasets in F:/Tiled_Shapes/ ? you can skip "*","All" on ListDatasets as they are the default values, inshape = arcpy.ListDatasets() will do the exact same thing.

Comment: @Midalvo: I'm using intersect because I want to retain the attributes of the prior *.shp's. Basically, this is one part of generating a classification error matrix, so I want to know the identity of both polygons prior to intersecting. Also, I added the print inshape. It didn't work at first, but after applying GISge's fix, it did. Thank you.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify which geoprocessing operation you're using: Clip or Intersect. They are not the same thing but you're using the terms interchangeably in your question *and* in your code, I'm a little worried you aren't doing the operation you think you're doing.

Comment: @Dan C: Its doing exactly what I expect it to be doing. Here, I'm using intersect like a clip, but retaining the spatial data from the both files. In this case I want to exclude data that isn't spatially coincident between the two.  I want to know what intersects what within the context of either shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, with arcpy list functions, it's always best to choose the most restrictive one (e.g. if you want to list rasters, use `arcpy.ListRasters()`, not `arcpy.ListFiles()`.

Even though a shapefile is a dataset, they're not included in the possible formats for [`arcpy.ListDatasets()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listdatasets.htm). So here, you should use [`arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) (technically a shapefile *is* a feature class, even if this term is mostly used for geodatabase feature classes).

And as @Midalvo mentioned, it's a good idea to use `print` statements to see what's returned by a list (or any function), when you don't get the expected results